# Splitting DEM based on elevation using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, elevation, splitting

I am trying to split a DEM TIFF file into three separate shapefiles (upland, middle and lowland) on ArcMap 10.6. I have used natural breaks to classify the DEM into three elevation categories.

How do I use this and split it further into different rasters which I can then create shapefiles from?

Comment: I dont think ArcMap provides this functionality out of the box. You can tinker with python to suite your needs here https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to split the raster at all. There are a couple ways to do it. One is to use two tools in succession:

1. Use [Reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to convert the elevation values in your raster. Use the natural breaks you've already found as the bins to reclassify your raster to just 3 values: 1 (lowland), 2 (middle) and 3 (upland).
2. Use [Raster to Polygon](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) to convert your reclassified raster to polygonal shapes. Use the field containing the 1-3 values as the Raster Field.

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! Further info: I then used 'split by attributes' tool to create individual polygons.